# microsoft.data.entity missing from MVC 6 (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I have created a MVC 6 project in Visual Studio 2015.

I am trying to create a Code First Entity framework class library

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "DB Class Library",
    "authors": [ "Michael" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",

    "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.0.10",
        "System.Data.Entity.Repository": "2.0.0.1",
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Data.Edm": "5.6.5-beta"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dotnet": { }
    }
}
```

This is my project.json file.

The tutorial now says I should add "Microsoft.Data.Entity" However I am missing this reference so I'm not able to add this library. I need this library so I can create my DBContext class.

Comment: Did you solved this? I am having the exact same issue on my project too.

Comment: Try changing the "frameworks setting. see here : http://www.sharepointpro.com.au/blog

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, the project did not load all the libraries in the beginning.  Added the hot fix and all is well now.

**Problem :**
Opening Package Manager Console produces the message:

"Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope. Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution policy of Unrestricted. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy"."

But no PowerShell prompt ever appears. Similarly, attempting to install a package produces the same message on attempting to execute the script file from the package, followed by:

Install failed. Rolling back...

Attempting to upgrade an existing package instead produces:

Failed to initialize the PowerShell host. If your PowerShell execution policy setting is set to AllSigned, open the Package Manager Console to initialize the host first.

**Solution**
Explained and hot fix links available in https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/974#issuecomment-124774650
A hotfix is now available to install and we are confident it will unblock you. Please grab the install from one of these locations appropriately:

3.1.1 for VS 2015:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/releases/download/3.1.1/NuGet.Tools.vsix

We will publish these to the Visual Studio gallery next week.

Answer (score 0):

Change dotnet to dnx451

```
"frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { }
    }
```